# Implementing Observer Pattern for my Rails App

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern, event-listener

I am currently using rails 3.0.7 and ruby 1.9.2 and making a rails App which contains a video being loaded from a database while being rendered by FlowPlayer. and a set of slides based on the video. Now, I wanted to synchronize the slides with the video. For the timings, I am asking the user to enter the timings of each slide. So, I was wondering if i could use observer pattern for this by making a sort of central time as the subject and the video and slides as the observers?

While, the concept seems correct after going through a number of tutorials on the net, I am not able to proceed or ge ideas on coding it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically, you have two choices:

use ActiveRecord's callbacks (before_save, after_save, etc..) or create an observer

```
# app/observers/some_model_observer.rb
class SomeModelObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :your_model # the model you're observing

  def after_create(record)
  end

  # other ActiveRecord callbacks
end
```

Comment: Hi Andrea.Thanks for the tip. Basically from your answer, i understand that i will have to link my video and slides models respectively in the observer file using the observe :<model>. Now, to synchronize them, i think every second should be triggered as an event and according to the timings, the slide changes and the video moves forward. How do i link the time and these observers. Thanks for the help. Sorry if my question sounds silly. I am quite a noob at this still.

Comment: Hi Saagar, the observers are basically for model related events. I think you should use some javascript for timings and syncing (read: no ruby or rails involed in this particular context)

Comment: Hi Andrea. Thanks for clearing that up! So does that mean, to achieve what i want, i have to completely use javascript and there is no Observer involved? Can u please elaborate a bit on model-related events?

Comment: for model events, check this doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html ;)

Comment: Nice!Thanks for that...:)...i came across this term called eventmachine which is an api for event-listener mechanism in ruby. Do you think that wud enable me to achieve what i want.Thanks for taking time out and the patience!!

Comment: I'd use eventmachine for server-related things. the best thing for your context is to use JS and/or AJAX. for small/few slides you can load them all, then use JS to switch slides every X time.