# different type of notifications [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, uml, database-schema

I am developing a feeds application with ruby on rails, and I want to show in the main page of the application some courses activities managing by the users.

Basically, the idea is a user can create a course, other users can follow the course and comment inside that event, later in the future, I Want that it will be more complex.

My solution is having a notifications table which manage all this. Above it shows the table which will have a feed type (1. create course, 2. pay the course, 3. comment into this group, 4. course deleted, 5. share course... and could be more). user_id field refiere to the user who should see the notification, message_id not nil only when the notification consist in add a comment.

```
<<Table>>
Feed
----------------
+ id : integer (Pk)
+ created_at : date_time
+ notification_type : string
+ text : text
+ course_id : integer (Fk)
+ user_id : integer (Fk)
+ comment_id : integer (Fk)
```

I am wondering if that would be the best implementation of this problem if I Want to make it more complex in the future. Please any feedback is welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're implementing the observer patter for this application. Based on your requirements, it looks like a fine implementation.

Here are some resources about this pattern.

http://www.sitepoint.com/design-patterns-in-ruby-observer-singleton/

[Implementing Observer Pattern for my Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395915/implementing-observer-pattern-for-my-rails-app)

Comment: Hi Isaffie thanks for the answer, it is interesting to control the issue with the observer class. That might work to save feed for example after creating a course or a comment...etc Moreover, what about my db solution? Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't use your db solution. You'll end up with a bunch of null fields when there's no user, comment, etc. I would normalize it some more and create more tables. Even think of using polymorphism. One table being feed and the other the type of feeds.

Comment: very interesting, I finally did it by polymorphism. now I have the doubt for example: given a course where are 7 students, when someone comment in the course group, that all students receive notification, should I create 7 notifications corresponding to those students or there is another way to do that. Thank you a lot! using this make the app really extendible.

Comment: You would just create one comment on the course and the students should be able to get notified/see the comment via the course they're enrolled in... student.courses.first.comments (for example)

Comment: how the enrolled students will get notified, I really don't have it clear yet. Knowing that in the main page of my application appear all the notifications related to the student connected, so the idea is that the comment notification appear in that page.

Comment: when a new comment comes, in the comment should grab the collection of students via the course and notify them all. @comment.course.notify_students

Comment: you would implement notify_students in course where it would send notifications to each student in the course collection. course.students.each....

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! I'll try to implement that way.

Comment: Hi Isaffie, I am back to you, I have another question. Actually I implemented the problem and it is working perfect, that users will have many feeds which is polymorphic, on the other hand, for each feed type it has_one :feed, as feedable. My question is when I will have millions of user using the system, I will have so many feeds in my db as well, that would be an inconvenient during my lectures to the db or it is normal. Thanks again!

Comment: That's how polymorphism is supposed to work. Make sure to add the appropriate indexes to your table to make the lookups fast.